# Reading suggestions on the historic development of the Arabic language

Tags: historical-linguistics, arabic

Specifically, I am looking for something:

- That isn't just an introduction, but neither a comprehensive "everything we can currently say on the topic" kind of text.
- That goes back to about Proto-Semitic, and doesn't talk just about starting from classical Arabic.
- Doesn't focus too heavily on only one aspect (e.g. just phonology or just morphology) and rather something a bit more balanced.

Just to clarify, I have pretty much no prior experience with The historical development of the Arabic language.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cutting-edge study by the leading scholar in the field. The book can be downloaded for free. Table of contents on the link.

https://www.academia.edu/38100372/Al_Jallad_A_Manual_of_the_Historical_Grammar_of_Arabic

Comment: Thank you, I have only begun to read it, but it seems interesting.